# Parse a JSON file and loop through objects in Puppet

Tags: json, puppet

I want to extract and loop through the value from a JSON file, but none of the puppet documentation has any examples or shows the right syntax of how to do this.

I have got this JSON file: [files.json]

```
[
    {
       "name": "test",
       "file_name": "test_test.txt"
    } 
]
```

In the puppet file I have tried: [get_files.pp]

```
$files = loadjson('C:\tmp\files.json')

$files.each |Integer $index| {
    $name = $files["${index}"][name]
    $file_name = $files["${index}"][file_name]

    notice("Name: $name and FileName: $file_name")
}
```

But it's not working maybe because of the wrong syntax or something else.

Another quick question here, just wondering if there is any better way of specifying the json path, as i cannot use specify the json file name directly like 'file.json' (which lives the same folder as the manifest)

I would expect to go through every object in that json file and assign the values to use in the puppet manifest file.

Hope you guys could help point out what i have missed out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Here is what I did to get the values from JSON file:

```
$examplefiles.each |Integer $index, Hash $examplefile| {

  $name = $examplefile['name']
  $filename = $examplefile['file_name']

}
```